# Jar file won't display resource after update from 7 to 10

Tags: java, jar

Often I use a certain jar file which displays a text file and allows you to filter the list in different ways.

This worked perfectly until I updated from Java 7 to Java 10.  Now it won't display the resource text file anymore.

Here is the where I got the jar file: https://github.com/dragan224/battle_cats_en_combos

In the root of the jar file are two .txt files which the jar uses inside of itself.  Is there some security setting that blocks this? Or did the version change make the code defunct?

In the code files, I can see it is using this:  `InputStream input = (InputStream) ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + cat_file_name);`

So, I've recompiled it and specified `-source 1.8` in the compilation string in the commandline, but it doesn't make any difference.

I don't even know how to figure out why it's not working.  When I run the commandline `javaw -jar CatCombos.jar` (my new compilation's name), it doesn't say anything on the commandline in response.  It runs, but doesn't display the text file, just like the original one.

This all started when I installed `jdk-10.0.2_windows-x64_bin.exe` just today.  Before that I was running 1.8 JRE and it worked fine.

**[update]**

I installed JDK 8.44 and ran the jar files with the javaw.exe from that folder and the jar application runs perfectly and displays the contents just fine.  So something is changed or I'm missing something to make Java 10 run the files properly.

**[update]**

Okay, so my question about *using* Java was migrated to Stack Exchange even though it was not a question about coding.  This was a mistake by somebody, and since this is now believed to be a coding question (in which no code was supplied in the first place) I'm going to suppose that the reason Java 10 didn't display the text file is because the code used for Java 8 is no longer viable.  Therefore, I'm going to present code and maybe resolve the question this way by turning it into a coding question.

Here is the code where I am loading the text file.

```
        InputStream input = (InputStream) ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + file_name);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
        //do something
        }
```

So, for the structure of the project, it is very simple, and goes like this (this is the first java project I've ever worked with, by the way):

```
/src
/src/javafiles (no subfolders; just .java files)
/src/textfile.txt  (the one I'm trying to load)
/manifest.txt (telling which java file to start up with)
/compile.bat
```

So, the textfile is in the parent folder of the java binaries.

**[update]**

After loading up the project into Eclipse (which I've never used before), I am seeing that I am getting a `null pointer error` on this line:

```
InputStream input = (InputStream)ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(combo_file_name);
```

Eclipse gives this description:

> Open Declaration   InputStream
>   java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream(String name)
>
> @CallerSensitive
>
> Finds a resource with a given name.
>
> If this class is in a named Module then this method will attempt to
>   find the resource in the module. This is done by delegating to the
>   module's class loader findResource(String,String) method, invoking it
>   with the module name and the absolute name of the resource. Resources
>   in named modules are subject to the rules for encapsulation specified
>   in the Module getResourceAsStream method and so this method returns
>   null when the resource is a non-".class" resource in a package that is
>   not open to the caller's module.
>
> Otherwise, if this class is not in a named module then the rules for
>   searching resources associated with a given class are implemented by
>   the defining class loader of the class. This method delegates to this
>   object's class loader. If this object was loaded by the bootstrap
>   class loader, the method delegates to
>   ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream.
>
> Before delegation, an absolute resource name is constructed from the
>   given resource name using this algorithm:  • If the name begins with a
>   '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion
>   of the name following the '/'.  • Otherwise, the absolute name is of
>   the following form:  modified_package_name/name
>
> Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object
>   with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').
>
> Parameters:name name of the desired resourceReturns:A
>   java.io.InputStream object; null if no resource with this name is
>   found, the resource is in a package that is not open to at least the
>   caller module, or access to the resource is denied by the security
>   manager.Throws:NullPointerException - If name is nullSince:1.1See
>   Also:Module.getResourceAsStream(String)@revised9@specJPMS

So, what do I do with this?  I'm thinking the .jar can't find the text file for some reason.

Here is how I address the files:

```
package catcombo;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainWindow("NyancomboData.txt", "Names.txt");
    }

}
```

Comment: `ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + cat_file_name)` seems dodgy. Why not `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream...`?

Comment: I didn't write this.  What I want to know is how to make it work now that I've updated to version 10.  It worked before; it was compiled some time last year using JavaSE-1.8.  I was running that version, but recently updated, and now the app runs but does not load the text files.  (This was a usage issue, which was why I posted on SuperUser and not StackExchange).

Comment: So I've recompiled it, and specified `-source 1.8` but that doesn't make any difference.  It runs, but doesn't display the text file.  I don't even know how to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @ernest_k I added some actual code to the question, if you would be so kind as to take a look.

Comment: Can you share the the structure of the project (including where the file is expected to be)?

Comment: Since this is a third party app you are using, can't you file a bug report on [github](https://github.com/dragan224/battle_cats_en_combos/issues)?

Comment: Yeah, I've done that, and several times, but the authour must have abandoned the project.  I'm trying to make it work for myself.  It works if I run it in Java 8, but not Java 10.

Comment: @ernest_k I think you were onto something...  It's that line that is the problem; the line I have (with Java 10 fails, in Java 8 it works) gives me a null pointer.  If I try your snippet, Java tells me for `this` *cannot load in a static context* - some problem in the way my class is built; I don't understand enough of what I'm doing to fix it.

Comment: If you're making that from a static method, then instead of `this.getClass()`, use `ClassName.class`, where `ClassName` is the name of the class in which that static method is defined...

Comment: Voila!  That was it!  Can you propose this as an answer so I can mark it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the updates from 1.8 to version 10, there must have been introduced a new strictness with the use of static methods within a class.

My code had

```
InputStream input = (InputStream) ClassLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + file_name);
```

When I changed it to

```
InputStream input = MyOwnClass.class.getResourceAsStream(file_name);
```

Then everything began to work perfectly.